# Where can I get the Java analysis libraries for the Rascal REPL

Tags: java, read-eval-print-loop, rascal

I've developed a Rascal program using Eclipse, but I'd like to be able to run it in the REPL. When I try to import some required libraries, I get error like this one:

```
|prompt:///|(0,33,<1,0>,<1,33>): Could not import module lang::java::jdt::m3::Core: File rascal://lang::java::jdt::m3::Core not found.
```

The Rascal website indicates these libraries are not included by default, but I cannot figure out where I should get them from and how I should use them. Is there any way to get the Java analysis libraries working in the Rascal REPL?

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside your rascal project in eclipse, there are two library folders, `rascal` and `rascal-eclipse`, only the libraries from the first folder actually work outside of eclipse.

For m3, there is a non eclipse version, but you will have to point the framework to the correct jar's and source folders, which is normally handled by eclipse. Take a look at `lang::java::m3::Core`.